# Azure DevOps yaml passing variable using "##vso[task.setvariable" not working

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In the following yaml stage (code given below), I am trying to convert parameter envList to specific env names.
e.g. envList = "NameDevEnv, NameQAEnv, NameStageEnv, NameProdEnv"

I am trying to pass NameDevEnv, NameQAEnv, NameStageEnv and NameProdEnv to separate variable/parameters in yaml and then pass these name to templates so those envs are created with the given names.

Following code is not printing the correct value for variable one. i.e. I am expecting the last statement, echo $(one) to print NameDevEnv.

Please advise / assist.
Thanks

```
stages:
  - stage: preWork
    jobs: 
     - job: convert_input
       continueOnError: false
       steps: 
         - script: |
              htring="${{parameters.envlist}}"
              echo $htring
              IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$htring"
              echo "${array[0]}"
              htringz="${array[0]}"
              
              echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue
              echo $(one)
              echo $htringz
             ## $htringz = $htring.split(",")[0]
           displayName: first vairable pass
         - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one;isOutput=true;]$htringz"
           displayName: set new variable value
         - script: |
               echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue
               echo $(one)
```

Comment: Remove the isOutput=true from the setvasiable. Output variables are referenced be the name of the task that sets them.

Comment: I did remove isOutput=true, but still its not showing me the value of $htringz.

Comment: Make sure you set the variable in the script block where you define `$htringz`. In the new block the environment is clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the value of htringz in task "first variable pass" and using the value in another task "set new variable value" as soon as the task change, the local variable of that task is not carried forward to another task.
If you want to set the value to variable one, do it in the same task.

Stage I used as an example, used bash instead of script as I prefer bash for statements like echo.

```
stages:
  - stage: preWork
    jobs: 
     - job: convert_input
       continueOnError: false
       steps: 
         - bash: |
              htringz="Test"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]$htringz"
           displayName: first vairable pass
         - bash: echo $(one)
```

Output
[image: Output 1]

Another stage with separate tasks for getting the value and separate task for setting the value

```
stages:
  - stage: preWork
    jobs: 
     - job: convert_input
       continueOnError: false
       steps: 
         - bash: |
              htringz="Test"
           displayName: first vairable pass
         - bash: |
               echo $htringz
               echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]$htringz"
               echo "=================="
               echo $(one)
```

Output
[image]

So, just set the value in the same task and it should work.
I hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: Hi,  I am trying to set value in one task/stage and then use it in another stage, the above variable one was declared as Env variable with a "null value",  however it is set in 'first variable pass' task and then trying to use it at later stages.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Also, the following code works very well, this is an example code from setting variable in one task and echoing it in second task.

`variables:
- name: one
  value: initialValue 

steps:
  - script: |
      echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue
      echo $(one)
    displayName: First variable pass
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue"
    displayName: Set new variable value
  - script: |
      echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue
      echo $(one) # outputs secondValue
    displayName: Second variable pass`

Comment: This is an example code from setting variable in one task and echoing it in second task, I got it from the Microsoft documentation page (link below), scroll down to 'Understand variable syntax'. You will find the example code. This code example when copied works as it is and displays the value of the variable one set in different tasks.
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

Comment: Basically, htringz="${array[0]}" and echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]$htringz" should be in same task

Comment: can you check this link?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: also, instead of using
- bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one;isOutput=true;]$htringz"

if i use, i.e. hardcoded value instead of passing through a variable or a parameter it works fine.
- bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one;isOutput=true;]yes"

Comment: yes, I saw that link.
The issue is with the value "$htringz", if the value of this local variable is empty.
The value of variable "one" will also be empty.

if you hardcode, then the value is not empty, thus setting up the value correctly

Comment: @lavoizer: that is why if you set the value of local variable $htringz in a task and then set the value of variable "one" in that exact same task, the value of one would not be empty.

Comment: even if the htringz is a globally declared variable the value is still empty.
All i am trying to do is get substrings from a delimited string taken at run time from user and pass it as parameters to different templates, how would you go about it?

Comment: this can be achieved like this
https://github.com/tejas-nagchandi/delimited-input-pass-to-template

Comment: First of all thank you so much! This is neat, however was I not doin the same thing? I guess I am missing something. You are also echoing these variable from different tasks, how is this able to work and mine was not working?

Comment: Because, I used the set variable on the same task where the values are not empty.
That is the one and only mistake you are making, rest all is absolutely correct.

Comment: understood, so essentially in my case if I was using set variable in the same task where we are setting the value of htringz then it would have worked too. Man you are awesome! thx

Comment: Happy to help!! Good luck

Comment: Updated path for github repo https://github.com/tejas-nagchandi/stackoverflowissues/tree/main/70010567

Answer (score 0):

As [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-the-same-job) point out, passing a variable between tasks requires setting the `isOutput=true` parameter on the variable. What they don't really explain is how this shows up in bash in the subsequent tasks. There are two key points:

1. You MUST give the task that sets the variable a name, for example `name: FOO`.
2. The bash task replaces the dot which normally appears between the task name and the variable name with an underscore. So in the example below, instead of `$(FOO.BAR)` (as would be used in Powershell), you use the bash syntax `${FOO_BAR}`.

Example:

```
- task: Bash@3
  name: FOO
  displayName: Set a variable for passing between tasks.
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BAR;isOutput=true]foobar"

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Use a variable in another task.
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "\${FOO_BAR} is '${FOO_BAR}'"
```

The example will output:

```
${FOO_BAR} is 'foobar'
```